# Finding the eigenvectors for a $2\times 2$ matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematica

Some lecture notes I’m reading present the following matrix:

\begin{equation*}
L = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a \\
b & c\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

It then says that the dominant eigenvalue $ \lambda$ is the solution to the characteristic equation $\lambda^2-c\lambda-ab=0$, which I think I follow.

My problem is that it then says the dominant left eigenvector is proportional to $[b \: \lambda]$ and the dominant right eigenvector is proportional to $[a \: \lambda]$. I am fairly new to matrix algebra, and I do not follow these steps. I would appreciate a simple explanation.

I’ve tried solving for these eigenvectors in Mathematica using the Eigensystem[] function (as ultimately I want to use a similar step on any 2x2 matrix as an automatic subsection in a larger script), but the output doesn’t seem to match the notes.

Comment: The characteristic equation is not what you wrote (and your $s$ is undefined). Not only the "dominant" eigenvalue is a root of the charactieristic equation. A row vector $u$ is a left eigenvector w.r.t. $\lambda$ iff $uL=\lambda u.$ A column vector $v$ is a right eigenvector w.r.t. $\lambda$ iff $Lv=\lambda v.$

Comment: Sorry, I messed up typing the characteristic equation in latex. Edited to correct it above.

Answer (score 1):

As previously noted, the characteristic equation $\lambda^2 - c\lambda - ab = 0$ gives both eigenvalues.  The roots are
$$
\lambda = \frac{c}{2} \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{c}{2}\right)^2 + ab},
$$
and I assume if these parameters are positive, both eigenvalues are real, and the dominant one is the positive case.

The eigenvalue equations for left and right eigenvectors:
$$
\mathbf{r}L = \lambda \mathbf{r}, \qquad L\mathbf c = \lambda \mathbf{c}
$$
are equivalent to
$$
\mathbf{r}(L-\lambda I) = \mathbf 0, \qquad (L-\lambda I)\mathbf c = \mathbf 0,
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.  Since
$$
L - \lambda I = \begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & a \\ b & c-\lambda \end{bmatrix},
$$
we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix} b & \lambda \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & a \\ b & c-\lambda \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}0 & ab - \lambda(c-\lambda) \end{bmatrix} = \boldsymbol 0,
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & a \\ b & c-\lambda \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ \lambda \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ ab - \lambda(c-\lambda) \end{bmatrix} = \boldsymbol 0.
$$
These formulas for the eigenvectors are true for both eigenvalues, not just the dominant (substitute in the given eigenvalue to get the given eigenvector).

Comment: Thanks for this. I think what I am struggling with is that $[b \: \lambda]$ appears to come out of the blue. Once it's suggested as the eigenvector, I can see that it fits. I tried using 'Eigensystem[]' in Mathematica, but the eigenvector it produced was a complicated function of all the variables in the $L$ matrix, not simply $[b \: \lambda]$.

Comment: You could think of it as follows: the first column of $A-\lambda I$ is $\begin{bmatrix} -\lambda &  b\end{bmatrix}^T$, and the inner (dot) product between the left eigenvector and each column of $A-\lambda I$ must be zero.  This is enough information to tell you that the eigenvector must be $[b,\lambda]$.  Whatever output you have got from Mathematica will be a scalar multiple of this vector (but not necessarily the exact same vector).